# Update devexpress components to v.19.2.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, devexpress

I want to update my devexpress components from v.16.2.4.0 to the newest version. I used already the Project Converter in Visual Studio to upgrade all projects. However when I look into the dependencies folder of the solution folder there is still v.16.2 and not the newest version. Any Idea what to do next?

[image]

Comment: What is *"dependencies order"* ?

Comment: Sorry I meant  the dependency folder (not order) in the solution. Look at the image, it has still the old version

Comment: To use new version components, you should add new components to Toolbox by choosing new version's Devexpress components. You can clean and rebuild solution after project converter process.

Comment: I have no idea what depedency folder term means. Is it something for asp.net?. How does your output folder looks like (the one where all dlls are copied during build)? Are there still old files? The folder on screen is even named specifically to devexpress version, that doesn't looks like output folder. It could be an artifact, not deleted by upgrading process folder, which is not even used by any of the projects. Are there more folders inside `dependencies` folder?

Comment: You must use **Assembly Deployment Tool**, Reference: https://docs.devexpress.com/AssemblyDeploymentTool/17237/assembly-deployment-tool